# Why does "to lift the law" actually mean to revoke it?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> After being defeated in several lower court rulings and suffering large financial losses, the city of Montgomery lifted the law mandating segregated public transportation.

From the context I can deduct that *to lift* means *to cancel*/*to revoke*. Why is it so? It doesn't seem logical to me, as in other contexts lifting means elevation and not the opposite.

Comment: You may find [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58909) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google's dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?espv=2&q=define%20lift&oq=define%20lift&gs_l=serp.3..0i67j0l9.4688.7275.0.7465.17.15.2.0.0.0.159.1008.10j2.12.0.esbd%2Csrna%3D10%2Csrs%3D20%2Ccfro%3D1.3..0...1.1.64.serp..3.13.963.0.ptOXAjWB8_Y) does just have "formally remove or end (a legal restriction, decision, or ban)." as a definition of lift, so in one respect that is just what it means.

However, I think that is related to another definition of lift from that result, "(of a cloud, fog, etc.) move upward or away." It isn't lift like "elevate" but rather "move away", like if a weight was lifted from your chest.

I also like to think of it this way:
Imagine laws like a cage. If you tighten the laws the cage is getting smaller/tighter with less freedom. If you lift the laws, it's like the ceiling of the cage is lifting higher, giving you more room/more freedom.

Comment: A common expressing when making or enforcing a law is **lay down the law**, "The new sheriff came to town to stop crime and lay down the law." **Lifting** would be the opposite.

Comment: Good point! I didn't think about that connection.

Answer (score 2):

The law has been lifted in the way that any other barrier or restriction is lifted. This is extended from the way that actual, literal barriers - ones which are erected on roadways at borders or tollbooths - get lifted.